# How can I remove the Featured Image in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-featured-image

I've searched the forums, but I think the code is too old now.  How can I remove the Featured Image in Woocommerce?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Try this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-featured-image/) and then  use a function to show the second image of the  gallery. Otherwise it will show the empty space that the featured image left.

Second option, try this snippet:

```js
function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
if(is_single()) {
return '';
} else

return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
```

[More useful info and options here.](https://www.webhostinghero.com/remove-featured-image-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!  I see that it hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress, but I may give it a try.  Thanks again!

Comment: I tested and  it worked with the latest version  for me. I was not  able to figure out how skip the blank space. I if you try it you will see what I mean. I think it will be better to find a Woocommerce snippet. I have provide you more info  in my comment.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try.